# Override method in multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have implemented my own memory manager and I override the new and delete operators like this:

```
/** Override the Standard C++ new operator */
void* operator new (size_t size);
/** Override the Standard C++ delete operator */
void operator delete (void *p);
```

This works ok, but now I'm developing in a multi-threaded environment with lots of heap allocation. To avoid heap contention, I want that each thread has its own memory manager instance. How can I make the operator overrides point to the memory manager instance for that thread?

Comment: Sounds like Thread Local Storage could work. Or you could have a thread-safe map from thread-id to memory manager instance.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows? Linux? Something else?

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov Windows, UNIX, and Linux.

Comment: Then it's tricky. You need TLS (thread-local storage mechanism). It is not provided by the C++ language and is instead implemented by an operating system. Thus, you will need a separate implementation for Windows and a separate implementation for Linux. Alternatively, you can use a library like boost that abstracts out those OS-specific APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread Local Storage could work.